# "invalid xaml" error in the designer

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am trying to use a listbox to display a custom UserControl. It had been working just fine until recently i started recieving an "invalid xaml" error message and am no long able to refresh the Design View.

The error does not keep the app from compiling and running.

I have tried everything i can think of. I created a test control and a test page from scratch and only get the error when i put the control in the data template. I can put any standard control into the data template without error. only errors on a custom usercontrol.

here is the page:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WP7ListBoxSelectedItemStyle"
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:testproject.Controls"
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
x:Class="WP7ListBoxSelectedItemStyle.TestPage"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="8,17,16,-17">
        <ListBox  Name="lb_test"
                        Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <my:Test1></my:Test1>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

and here is the usercontrol (no added code in the codebehind):

```
<UserControl x:Class="testproject.Controls.Test1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
Height="80" Width="80">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: `<ListBox  Name="lb_test"` should be "x:Name". A Copy/Paste error?

Comment: Ya I think Kookiz found your culprit, if its a XamlParseException and just says something vague like Line: 0 Position: 0 it's usually some mundane syntax typo in a visual reference of some sort so you look at your elements that would be rendered visually and the syntax they use.

Comment: the missing "x:" is just a copy/paste error, but doesn't fix the problem. The error message is just "invalid xaml". you can see from the code there isn't anything to find. 1 completely empty control and 1 listbox. i still don't know how to resolve this

Comment: I have narrowed the problem down to a single folder. I have a folder called "Controls". And only usercontrols in that folder have a problem. I am going to try moving them to a different folder and see if that helps.

Comment: disregard last comment... after re-building the project I found this to be false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out based on this post

http://forums.silverlight.net/post/618518.aspx

I cannot believe I added a space to my assembly name. ARG!

Answer (score 0):

1. Sometimes this is triggered by missing resources.
2. There is also a missing </UserControl> tag.

try:

```
<UserControl x:Class="testproject.Controls.Test1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Height="80" Width="80">

  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is a error in the editor... the </UserControl> is there it just didn't show up in the post. I will check for missing resources.

Comment: i have looked over all resources. There is none that could possibly be missing. Still don't have a solution